# How to send extra parameter in stripe charge.

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am integrating stripe payment gateway. i have integrated it successfully. but the problem is that i want to send exptra parameter for stripe one time and get that in response. 
Now i using

```
               Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                    "amount" => number_format($amount,2,".","")*100,
                    "currency" => AccountCurrency,
                    "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                    "description" => "Desc: " . $custom
                ));
```

I want to send extra partameter like order_id and want that from response as stripe give customer id for recurring charge.

```
       Stripe_Charge::create(array(
                    "amount" => number_format($amount,2,".","")*100,
                    "currency" => AccountCurrency,
                    "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                    "description" => "Desc: " . $custom,
                    "Order_id => $order  // Is there any method to send paramerte like this.
                ));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the metadata attribute. See below -

```
Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => number_format($amount, 2, ".", "")*100,
    "currency" => AccountCurrency,
    "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
    "description" => "Desc: " . $custom,
    "metadata" => array("order_id" => $order)
));
```

Check the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#metadata)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get Logged Customer Id using Logged User's Email
Dictionary<string, string> Extra = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Extra.Add("email", ByEmail);
StripeCustomer customer = customerService.List(new StripeCustomerListOptions() { Limit = 1, ExtraParams = Extra }).SingleOrDefault();
```